Spark SQL deterministic `sample` table behaviour
I’m working with Apache Spark 3.5.0 and I’m using Spark SQL to sample data from a large table. However, I need to ensure that the sampling behavior is deterministic, meaning that the same subset of data is selected each time I run the query.
Thanks

spark sql
Using TABLESAMPLE with REPEATABLE
TABLESAMPLE can be specified in many ways (refer to documentation), and use REPEATABLE for deterministic behaviour. The syntax is as follows:
SELECT * FROM your_table
TABLESAMPLE (percentage_value PERCENT) REPEATABLE (seed_value);

Using rand() Function with a Seed
Alternatively, you can use the rand() function with a fixed seed in the WHERE clause to sample rows. This method allows more flexibility but requires specifying the desired proportion manually.
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE rand(seed_value) < sampling_fraction;

